# How do I store data in memory & be able to update it without race conditions in django?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I plan to use the session to store user preference data.
Is there a cas like API for session like [this one](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2011/08/compare-and-set-in-memcache.html) in appengine ?
The use case: concurrent ajax calls might update the same object; thus there should no race conditions. I am using Django 1.3

Answer (score 2):

Neither Python or Django does this for memory. Use Memcache directly, or Redis (my preferred method), or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Python includes a sqlite3 module which has an in-memory option.  Sqlite3 also manages concurrency, assuring atomic commits.